# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\test_USSD2\listener.php on line 46

Tags: php

I'm trying to select from the database however im getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\wamp\www\Project\USSD_Misec\test_USSD2\listener.php on line 46

this is my code:

```
<?php
    include "func/database.php";

    //$db = new Database();
    $db =new  Database('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database_name');
    $db->connect();


    $data = file_get_contents("php://input"); 
    $line = "\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    file_put_contents("logs/ussdgw.txt", $data."\n", FILE_APPEND);  

    $dataDecoded = json_decode($data);  

    $uri = array_reverse(explode("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));
    $usid = $uri[1];
    $action = $uri[0];



    $defaultmenu = array(
        "shouldClose" => false,
        "ussdMenu" => "Hello Welcome to Misec..., choose :
        1.Enrolment Enquiry 
        2.Enrolment Date 

        3.Exit",
        "responseExitCode" => 200,
        "responseMessage" => ""
        );

    switch($action)
    {
        case 'response':    

                switch($dataDecoded->text) 
                {
                    case 1:
                        $ussdMenu = "1. Enrolment Enquiry";
                        $q = "SELECT * FROM ussd ORDER BY id DESC";
                        $r = $db->query($q);
                        // if we have a result loop over the result
                        if($db->num_rows($r) > 0){
                            while($a = $db->fetch_array_assoc($r)){

                                echo "{$a['id']} wrote $a['name']\n";

                            }

                        }
                    break;
                    case 2:
                        $ussdMenu = "2. Enrolment Date";
                    break;
                }   
            $response = array(
                "shouldClose" => true,
                "ussdMenu" => $ussdMenu,
                "responseExitCode" => 200,
                "responseMessage" => ""
            );
            $r_encoded = json_encode($response);
            echo $r_encoded;
        break;

        case 'status':
            $sessions = file_get_contents("logs/sessions.txt");
                $sessionsActive = explode("\n", $sessions);
                    if(in_array($usid, $sessionsActive))
                        $sessionActive = true;
                    else 
                        $sessionActive = false;

                    $end = array(
                        "sessionActive" => $sessionActive,
                        "responseExitCode" => 200,
                        "responseMessage" => ""
                    );
                $endEncoded = json_encode($end);
                echo $endEncoded;   
        break;

        case 'start':
            echo json_encode($defaultmenu);
            file_put_contents("logs/sessions.txt", $usid."\n", FILE_APPEND);    
        break;

        case 'end':

            $sessions = file_get_contents("logs/sessions.txt");
                $sessionsActive = explode("\n", $sessions);
                    unset($sessionActive[$usid]);
                $sessionsModified = implode("\n", $sessionActive);
                file_put_contents("logs/sessions.txt", $sessionsModified); 


            $end = array(
                "responseExitCode" => 200,
                "responseMessage" => "Connection ended"
            );
            $endEncoded = json_encode($end);
            echo $endEncoded;
        break;
}
```

Comment: Change `echo "{$a['id']} wrote $a['name']\n";` to `echo $a['id'] . " wrote " . $a['name'] . "\n";`

Comment: @Fred-ii- But how will that change that the `echo` is unexpected? Doesn't this only solve the `unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE`?

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Thanks, but I rather wait for the OP. This is actually a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/26136518/ that OP posted already.

Comment: @kingkero OP isn't concatenating properly.

Comment: Its a duplicate because I edited it the last time but i didn't get the answer afterward, anyway i commented that line and i echoed a line that says hello but im getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

You've enclosed one of the variables in braces, which is correct, but not the second one.  Change the following line:

```
echo "{$a['id']} wrote $a['name']\n";
```

to:

```
echo "{$a['id']} wrote {$a['name']}\n";
```